# Error with implicit copy constructor in struct initialization

Tags: c++

I have come up with a problem that I am unable to explain in light of my knowledge of C++.

I have a class that takes a constant reference to a struct of type X but when I pass an argument of type X (which i previously initialized) I get an error from the compiler saying it can't convert to the first member of a member of X. This doesn't make any sense to me.

The error is similar in clang and g++ which leads me to think I am missing something egregious.

`error: no viable conversion from 'const Foo::X' to 'Foo::FooTypes'`

Why is it trying to convert from X to FooTypes which is the first member of Z?

```
class Foo {
public:
    enum FooTypes {
        JPEG
    };
    struct Z {
        FooTypes type;
        int a;
    };

    struct X {
        Z caps;
        double host_address;
    };
    Foo(const X& x);
private:
    const X x;
};

Foo::Foo(const Foo::X& x) :
                x{x}    {
}
int main() {
    Foo::X new_x = {
        {Foo::JPEG, 1}, 1.58 };
    Foo *s = new Foo(new_x);
    delete s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get this on Clang 3.6, but not 3.7 or 3.8 (HEAD). I also get it on GCC 4.9.2, but not 5.1.0, 5.2.0, or 6.0.0 (HEAD).

Comment: I get the same error on g++4.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use round brackets instead of curly brackets:

```
...
    const X m_x;
};
Foo::Foo(const Foo::X& x) :
    m_x(x) {
}
...
```

here is list initialization:

```
...
m_x{x.caps, x.host_address}
...
```

**Edit**
@PauloNeves
I just found Bjarne Stroustrup's document http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2640.pdf, which contains next definition:

> The general idea of "initializer lists" (as discussed for many years
>   in EWG) is to allow the use of a brace-enclosed list of expressions in
>   all contexts that allow initializers. The following list is lifted
>   from N2532:
>
> - Variable initialization; e.g., X x {v};
> - Initialization of a temporary; e.g,  X{v}
> - Explicit type conversion; e.g. x   X{v};
> - Free store allocation; e.g. p   new X{v}
> - Return value; e.g., X f(){ /* ... */ return {v}; }
> - Argument passing; e.g., void f(X); /* ...  */ f({v});
> - Base initialization; e.g., Y::Y(v) : X{v} { /* ... */ };
> - Member initialization; e.g., Y::Y(v) : mx{v} { X mx; /* ... */ };

I think that described **Member initialization** is your case. So as for me it looks like g++4.9 defect.

Comment: Indeed this works but can you explain why list initialization is wrong here? The only difference is that List-initialization prohibits narrowing conversions. Is it happening here?

Comment: It's look for me like a bug of g++4.9.2.

Comment: @PauloNeves `X` is an aggregate; in some versions of the C++ spec, aggregate initialization took precedence over copy-construction if you used braced initialization. This was fixed in a defect report in late 2014 , you may be using a compiler that doesn't implement that defect resolution

Comment: @PauloNeves See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1467

Comment: @NickK I will accept your answer when you add that this a defect. This way it remains for future reference the why.